# Trouble with merging code

Tags: git, github

My friend and I are working on a project on GitHub.

He recently pushed code to the repo which I didn't have and I already wrote some code, which isn't pushed. Meaning, the repo on GitHub has his commit but my local repo doesn't have that commit, so it's a commit behind. But I've made some changes of my own to the local repo, which I don't want to lose.

Now I'm stuck, I can't push without removing his code, and I can't pull without removing my changes. So how do I keep both the changes? I've heard of merge, but I can't figure out how to get his commit and merge it with mine.

How do I keep both mine and his changes?

Comment: Semi-related: [What's the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commit your changes to your local repo. Then you execute

```
git pull
```

which will merge his changes with yours, or

```
git pull --rebase
```

which will rewrite your changes on top of his changes, as if you had written them after.

Of course, whatever the strategy you choose, there is a possibility for conflicts, that you'll have to resolve. Follow the instructions.

This is covered by any Git book, and several are available for free online. Look them up.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* pull without removing your changes. What `git pull` does behind the scenes is equivalent to:

```
git fetch remote
git merge remote/branch
```

Therefore your changes will be safe and the changes of your coworker will be included. A new merge commit is created to merge the diverged working copies.

In the cases you did not make any changes `git` normally does a Fast Forward, which will set your state to the others. `git` only does this when it is safe to do so!

---

In case you did not commit your changes yet: Either commit them or read up about `git stash`, `git` won't allow you to `pull` until it is safe to do so!